# Is it possible to parse HTML together with its style components in a css file, into jsPDF `doc.fromHTML()`? Using React for my HTML components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jspdf

[image]

Here is my current code using Reactjs which results in the rendering of the above HTML components in my webpage.
I want the block shown in the image to appear in my PDF using jsPDF doc.fromHTML() method.

```
import React from 'react';

const Pdf = () => {
    return (
        <div className="grid-container">
           Some words
        </div> 
    );
}

export default Pdf;
```

Here are codes for jsPDF.

```
const htmlstring = renderToString(<Pdf />);
let doc = new jsPDF();
console.log(htmlstring);
doc.fromHTML(htmlstring);
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

however, this code results in a completely blank .pdf file.

Is it possible to use renderToString() as I did above to get a HTML string together with its styling? Is there any available way to obtain a HTML string that can be passed into doc.fromHTML() such that the output PDF will have all the styling included in the HTML string?

Comment: read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html. I think that you must use: import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'; and then ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Pdf />)

Comment: @Yakalent , I did an import already. I did import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server"; at the top

Comment: long back have faced a requirement like this, may be bit vary from your's. Anyhow importing my demo in this,it may help you, PDF download happens every time page loads https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bgir3o